Calling a Java Method from C++ in QT6 for putting android app in Immersiveamode
I need to call a Java method in Qt6. I want to put the android app in Immersive mode.
Here is my Java code:
package com.print;
import android.view.View;
import org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtActivity;

public class ImmersiveModeHandler {

    private QtActivity mActivity;

    public ImmersiveModeHandler(QtActivity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public void enableImmersiveMode() {
        View decorView = mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }

    public void disableImmersiveMode() {
        View decorView = mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}

I am calling this from C++ as
QJniObject MyJavaClass1;

MyJavaClass1 = QJniObject("com/print/ImmersiveModeHandler",
                                    "(Landroid/content/Context;)V",
                                    QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context());


 MyJavaClass1.callMethod<void>("enableImmersiveMode");

Getting below Exception:
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.print.ImmersiveModeHandler.enableImmersiveMode() on null object


Error indicates that the MyJavaClass1 QJniObject might be null when you attempt to call callMethod. Make sure you're passing the correct context to the constructor. Also ImmersiveModeHandler object might not be created before calling callMethod.
